# Insert in a temporal table the names of another table SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

Is there a way to have something like:

```
id NameColumn 
--------------
1  sex
2  age 
3  weight
4  height
```

...from a known table:

```
sex age weight height....
--------------------------
m   12    200  200
f   22    100  150
...
```

This is because I have like 300 fields so I would like to maker a map table.

Comment: Looks like you're really after a dynamic UNPIVOT...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have a known table

```
create table known (sex char(1), age int, weight int, height int)
```

This gives you the output required

```
select
    [id] = ORDINAL_POSITION,
    [NameColumn] = COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'known'
```

Output:

```
id          NameColumn
----------- -----------
1           sex
2           age
3           weight
4           height
```

If you wanted to create a table out of it, something like

```
select
    [id] = ORDINAL_POSITION,
    [NameColumn] = COLUMN_NAME
into #temporal
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'known'
```